# Missing :action key on routes definition Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error:

`Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.`

For this route

```
resources :groups do
  post '/groups/:id/add', on: :member
end
```

I have looked at several other SO answers on this but am not able to find one that helps me. What `action` is it missing?

Answer (score 1):

Key `action` here means controller action. as in

```
resources :groups do
  post '/groups/:id/add', on: :member, action: "add"
end
```

Rails can't infer the action from a path. But you can define the action instead and rails will automatically figure out the path:

```
resources :groups do
  post :add, on: :member
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to define routes. Actually router's member/collection accepts a key-value pair to generate the route. As you are defining a `member` function it will be like:

```
resources :groups do
  member do
    post :add
  end
end
```

It will generate a route like: `groups/1/add`

If you use `collection` then it will generate: `/groups/add`

```
resources :groups do
  collection do
    post :add
  end
end
```

Hope you get the idea.

**Or**
You can define specific route for this particular action like below:

```
match "/groups/:id/add" => "groups#add", via: :post
```